# angular js ng-repeat in arrayList

Tags: angularjs, json

i have array list how to loop in ng-repeat

```
$http({
  url: '/Home/USelection',
  method: "POST",
  data: formdata,
  dataType: 'json',
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  debugger;
  console.log(response.data);
  $scope.Subjects = response.data;


<div ng-repeat="s in Subjects" class="list-group-item">
  <label>{{s.Subjectname}}</label>
  <label>{{s.Yearid}}</label>
  <label>{{s.Examtypeid}}</label>
  <label>{{s.Codefrom}}</label>
  <label>{{s.Codeto}}</label>
</div>
```

but in Browser array list like this

[image]

my out put not showing 
[my out put is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peFOS.jpg)

Comment: What is your exact problem?  are you getting any error??

Comment: What do you want as output? Everything seems okay here. Your Subjects is an array of object.SOo ng-repeat will work fine

Comment: but the it not showing out put what is expected

Comment: Can you post your full code ?

Comment: please put what is the error shown in console or add fiddle of ur code

Comment: Can you show me your full controller code? I don't know if you are implementing proper way of angularjs.

Comment: I think your controller is not loaded on that particular html.

Comment: thank you all for your feed back i did a mistake i find my self actually i'm put my code out of controller.

Comment: I think you didn't parse your json and can you tell me which version are you using

Comment: Use `'jsonp',` isntead of `'json',`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want or you just not share full code so, but it will helpful to you,

```
.factory('movieService', function($http, $log, $q) {
  return {
   getMovie: function(movie) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + movie)
       .success(function(data) { 
          deferred.resolve({
             title: data.title,
             cost: data.price});
       }).error(function(msg, code) {
          deferred.reject(msg);
          $log.error(msg, code);
       });
     return deferred.promise;
   }
  }
 });
```